# What properties should the column in GROUP BY Clause have in SQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

I've found group by to be very confusing topic in SQL. The database vendor doesn't matter to me but I'm using MySQL.

Till now, I've done lots of reading, and I'm still unable to determine what the properties of column should be that we want to use in GROUP BY clause?

Is it that the column in the group by clause should functionally determine the columns in select query? Or what it is?

Comment: The properties of the column hsve slmost nothing to fo with group by. You use it, when you need it.

Comment: Group by is used to group together rows based on a value. You can combine it with aggregate functions. Perhaps trying it out for yourself helps you understand the concept more than reading. Find a database sandbox and have fun

Answer (score 1):

While GROUP BY is often followed by a list of columns, it actually evaluates a list of **expressions**.

These expressions are evaluated for every row extracted from the DB (after applying JOINS and WHERE clauses). The rows for which the expressions evaluate with the same values are grouped together and the DBMS return to the user only one row for the whole group.

So the 'problem' is not what expression you can use to group the rows (you could use everything, even constants, boolean conditions or random numers) but what the DBMS should return as the single row for the whole group.

For example, with this table

```
CREATE TABLE test (a INT, b TEXT);
```

I could do:

```
SELECT max(a)
FROM test
GROUP BY a > 10;
```

This would create two groups, one where `a > 10` is FALSE and one where it is TRUE.
For both groups, the DBMS would return the highest value of `a` in the group.

However, in the following query:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM test
GROUP BY a > 10;
```

The DBMS would throw an error, because, while it's perfectly able to create the same two groups of rows as before, it doesn't know what value to pick for returning a single value to the user. Which value of `a` or `b` should it pick?

Even if some DBMS accept these syntax and don't throw an error, they would pick a random value based on some internal mechanism that you don't know and you cannot predict.

So, to summarize, the expressions in the GROUP BY determine how many rows you want in the final result (you get one row for each different combinations of values that exist in the table).

The expressions in the SELECT determine what result should be returned for each of those groups, and these results must either be something that all the rows in the group have in common (for example one of the expressions that appear in the GROUP BY) or something that can be computed from the rows in the group (an aggregate function like count(), min() or max(), for example).

Answer (score 0):

The "GROUP BY" clause defines the "level" at which you want to produce totals:

For example ...

```
GROUP BY Country, State, City
```

... will generate lots of fairly small totals (one per city), whereas ...

```
GROUP BY Country
```

... will generate a much smaller number of much larger (numerically) totals.

The Data Types of the columns used are largely *irrelevant*.
Your DBMS will be able to group by most, if not all, of its available Data Types.

What *does* matter - and this is only really a concern for MySQL, which allows you to do it *wrongly* - is that every column that you in your SELECT clause must be
**EITHER** included in the Group By clause
**OR** be wrapped in an Aggregate Function - SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), etc.

Consider this example:

```
+------------+---------------+-------+
| state      | city          | value | 
+------------+---------------+-------+
| California | San Francisco |    22 | 
| California | Redmond       |    33 | 
+------------+---------------+-------+

SELECT country, city, SUM( value )
FROM Table1
GROUP BY country ;
```

Totals will be generated at the level of `state` - OK.
`value` will be totalled up for each state - OK.
Which value of `city` should be returned?

Within the "grouping" of California, the database has a "choice" of two (San Francisco and Redmond) and *no way* to determine *which* it should return.  At this point, most DBMSes give up (with an error).  MySQL, depending on how it's configured, will return an "arbitrary" value (a.k.a. "any old value").  Which one is largely "undefined" and could even change between query executions.  Clearly, this is a Bad Thing.

The *default* MySQL configuration has [finally] joined the club and also throws an error when faced with this kind of "ambiguous" group by clause.